# Select highest value from equation involving two fields per group

Tags: mysql

I have a list of countries with the following fields:

- Old GNP
- New GNP
- Continent
- Name

I'd like to display a table such that

```
| Continent | GNP Increase | Country Name 
| Europe    | 60           | United Kingdom
| Asia      | 54           | United Emerates
....
```

Where only one country is shown per continent where that country has the highest GNP Increase in its continent.

I'm working out GNP Increase using: `(((GNP / GNPOld) / GNP) * 100)`, I have the following mysql however it's not getting the correct country (it is getting the highest GNP Increase per continent)

```
Select  a.Continent, 
        Max(((a.GNP - a.GNPOld) / a.GNP) * 100), 
        b.Name 
From    Country     as a 
Join    Country     as b    on  (((a.GNP - a.GNPOld) / a.GNP) * 100) = (((b.GNP - b.GNPOld) / b.GNP) * 100) 
Group By Continent;
```

So that it selects the highest GNP Increase for the continent and then attempts to attach a country from the same continent with the same GNP Increase (calculated w/ that formula above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `sub query` and `join`

```
select 
    a.Continent,
    b.GNP_Increase,
    a.Name
from Country as a
join (
    select
        Continent,
        max(((a.GNP - a.GNPOld) / a.GNP) * 100) GNP_Increase
    from Country
    GROUP BY Continent
) b
on (((a.GNP - a.GNPOld) / a.GNP) * 100) = b.GNP_Increase and
a.Continent = b.Continent
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time - I've just managed to get the answer myself; so this is the  correct answer, so Take the accept - friend.